# Multiplexer/Relay - USB Controlled

Tags: relay, multiplexer

I would like to measure the voltage of 80 analog outputs of my device but I only have 5 AI available. I am looking for Multiplexer/Relay Board off-the-shelf that is controlled via USB. Is there any product in the market that fulfills these requirements?

I have been surfing the web but I don't find anything with these specs.

Comment: Does it have to be off-the-shelf controlled by USB? What is the device, did you build it? If you designed and built it then it's odd to not be willing to put extra chips on the next version

Comment: Usually the ADC has 4 or even 8 channels. Many of them have I2C or SPI interface. So it should be easy to put 16 of them on the I2C or SPI bus to get 80 muxed ADC channels.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't built the device.

Comment: Since you have five analog inputs, five 16:1 analog multiplexers will give you those 80 channels.    USB sounds like an awkward addition to the problem, since four external logic address bits suffices  to address all the channels.

Answer (score 0):

You could *very* easily make your own - get enough of these for however many channels you want: https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/SparkFun/BOB-09056 then drive them form something like an arduino nano - which itself already has an inbuilt USB connection.
With about a dozen lines of code, you could read all 80 channels and send the data over USB back to your computer.